# Cleaning URL with tuckey URL Rewrite

Tags: jsp, url, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a settings.jsp page which has two links account and profile. settings.jsp?tab=account will show account settings and settings.jsp?tab=profile will show profile settings, I want to clean url for settings.jsp?tab=account to settings/account, below is the rule that i wrote(non-working).

```
<rule>
    <from>^/settings/account$</from>
    <to>/settings.jsp?tab=account</to>
</rule>
```

can anybody tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: The rule looks fine. I tested it and it worked. Don't you get the correct page when you enter 'http://localhost:8080/settings/account' in your Browser? Or are just the links not working?

Comment: @StefanBirkner when I go to 'localhost:8080/settings/account' it finds the html and get the page, but its not getting css file. Path to css file is "css/style.css", when i inspect element and add "../" to the path (../css/style.css), then the css is getting applied, that means it is considering settings as a folder directory, and gets the css file when ../ is added

Comment: You should have told this in your question. The problem is that the CSS is retrieved by the browser. The Browser is at the page 'localhost:8080/settings/account' and therefore looks at 'localhost:8080/settings/account/css/style.css'.

Comment: so what should be the solution now?